# how to get the view source page of a url that have already logged-in in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, url, view-source

I want to open a url which I have already logged into in Chrome, and this line of code successfully opens it in Chrome:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url]
```

However the source page is not coming through using this line of code:

```
NSString *webSource = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
```

Is there any special case with this. How can I get the view page source programatically?

Comment: For a browser connection that has authentication, if you're not seeing a session ID or some other unique identifier thing as part of the URL, then there's almost certainly some token or authentication bits being set via a cookie in your Chrome browser which can't magically transfer to your native app.

Comment: find out if there's a way to pass along the authentication token via a parameter in the URL, which you can then incorporate into the URL you pass to your program.